# How to correctly change const object?

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` of program parameters that were supposed to not change during the run of the program, i.e. after its initialization at the start I am just passing `const A&` everywhere. Now I needed to add a new parameter `duble p` to the class whose value I do not know at the start of the program but I need to assign it later. I know there are different ways how to change const object (by pointers or const_cast) but what is the best practice here? What is a safe way to do this and remain the program easy to read.

Is this OK (safe & clean) or should it be done differently?

```
class A
{
public:
    /* bunch of parameters which are initialized in constructor of A */
    double p; /* not change in constructor */
};

void change_p(const A& par)
{
    *(&par.p) = 5;
}

int main()
{
    A par();
    change_p(par);
}
```

Comment: The best approach might be to not add argument `p` to `A`. Perhaps you couldr bundle the const `A` and the recently determined `p` in another class.

Comment: if you must, you can mark it as `mutable`, but there's only a few cases where its a good idea

Comment: seeing `const_cast` in code is generally considered a design flaw.  It is generally reserved for cases when you are interfacing with a C api that doesn't use `const`.  The problem with casting away `const` is you don't know if the variable is actually `const` or just being given through a `const` interface.  The former if you modify the value you have undefined behavior.

Comment: "best practice" would be to not do this. Is there no other way you can organize your program?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: This could conceivably be one of those cases. E.g., a lazy getter that loads the member on first get.

Comment: Is the variable `const` or not? If it is, then don't change it. If it is not, then don't claim it is.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The variable was `const` for a long time, i.e. whole program now is written with the variable as `const`. The problem is that now (a year later than I wrote `class A`) I need to add a few parameters and I do not want to rewrite the whole program

Comment: If those function that need to modify the object are few then maybe you could add wrapper functions that take a *non-const reference*? The wrapper function can call the function that takes a *const reference* and then modify what it needs to change.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: There's nothing to do with `mutable` here because it is a function parameter not a member data.

Comment: Figure out a way to defer the creation of `A` until you actually have all the data needed to construct `A`. If `A` can work without this parameter, then write a new class as suggested. If either of these is hard, take the time to refactor the program.

Comment: Otherwise perhaps you could make the member variables that should be `const` into `const` members and change all the function parameters to *non-const references*?

Comment: Use: `const_cast<A&>(par.p) = 0 `

Comment: @vu1p3n0x the `mutable` seems to be and easy way around. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `double` as `mutable`, then it can be changed even if the object is `const`:

```
class A
{
public:
    /* bunch of parameters which are initialized in constructor of A */
    mutable double p; /* not change in constructor */
};

void change_p(const A& par)
{
    par.p = 5; // <-- OK, even though par is const!
}

int main()
{
    A par;
    change_p(par);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/c9IOHL)